# Error installing cordova

Tags: cordova, npm, browserify, visual-studio-cordova, jsonstream

**After running this command:**

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

**I get this error:**

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: JSONStream@'>=1.0.3-0 <2.0.0-0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.3.3","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","0.4.4","0.5.0","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.6.2","0.6.3","0.6.4","0.7.0","0.7.1","0.8.0","0.7.2","0.7.3","0.7.4","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.8.3","0.8.4","0.9.0","0.10.0"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Help would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: issue has been fixed via https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8985

It is a temporary issue due to a bad configuration, that will be fixed pretty soon I believe.

In the meantime, you can use the version 4 via `sudo npm install -g cordova@4.0.0` and update later today when it will be fixed.

Comment: We're seeing the same error trying to install cordova@4.3.0. Any idea which library is requiring JSONStream with those versions?

Comment: I quickly looked and haven't found it. if it is not fixed by this afternoon, I will look at it and report it.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to install cordova@4.2.0.

Comment: Any version of Cordova that depends on broswerify will hit this problem due to the issue @Victor mentions. Older versions do not use it and thus are unaffected. 4.1.2 works but 4.3.0 does not. There are similar threads going on related to broswerify and the npm folks are also involved.

Comment: The problem is fixed. Please try again.